# I want to extract the numbers at the end of a url using regular expressions in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I want to get '25430989' from the end of this url.

https://www.example.com/cars-for-sale/2007-ford-focus-1-6-diesel/25430989

How would I write it using the xpath?

I get the link using this xpath:
link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()

When I use a regex tester I can isolate it with r'(\d+)$ but when I put it into my code it doesn't work for some reason.

```
import scrapy
import re
from ..items import DonedealItem

class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'farmtools'
    allowed_domains = ['www.donedeal.ie']
    start_urls = ['https://www.donedeal.ie/all?source=private&sort=publishdate%20desc']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = DonedealItem()
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')

        for row in rows:
            if row.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[contains(text(),"0 min")]/text()'):

                link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get() #this is the full link.
                linkid = link.re(r'(\d+)$).get()
                title = row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').get()
                county = row.xpath('.//li[contains(text(),"min")]/following-sibling::node()/text()').get()
                price = row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
                subcat = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/text()[2]').get()

                items['link'] = link
                items['linkid'] = linkid
                items['title'] = title
                items['county'] = county
                items['price'] = price
                items['subcat'] = subcat

                yield items
```

I'm trying to get the linkid.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
            link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get() #this is the full link.
            linkid = link.re(r'(\d+)$).get()
```

When you use the `.get()` method it returns a string that is saved in the `link` variable, and strings don't have a `.re()` method for you to call. You can use one of the methods from the re module ([docs for reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents)).

I would use `re.findall()`, it will return you a **list** of values that matches the regex (in this case only one item would return), or `None` if nothing matches. `re.search()` is also a good choice, but will return you an `re.Match` object.

```
import re #Don't forget to import it

            ...
            link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            linkid = re.findall(r'(\d+)$', link)
```

Now, the **Scrapy selectors also [support](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) regex**, so an alternative would be implementing it like this: (No need for re module)

```
            linkid = row.xpath('.//a/@href').re_first(r'(\d+)$')
```

*Notice I didn't use `.get()` there.*

Comment: Thanks again renatodvc